# How to run jar app in a server and connect it to the frontend website?

Tags: java, php, server, frontend

I have a fully functional java application(with .jar extension) that can be hosted on a server.

I have a front end website(php) that needs to accesses that application and provide the resultant data that comes out of the application.

What is the best way to do that ? Or am I missing some logic in here?

as of now the app is built as a mac application with a GUI interface where the user has to get the application installed on their workstation. Thus, deciding to move the app to server and provide an unique website where the frontend can access the app hosted on the server

Comment: do you mean your php server needs to access the jar file? Javascript and front end tags are totally not applicable here

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your java application to rest service, if you want to get data from java application for your frontend application. If your app's architecture is well design it will not be a big deal.

Comment: indeed. a gui application wouldn't work - a cli app would, but turning it into a rest-interfacing app would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a front-end site running PHP, you are likely either running *apache* or *nginx*.

Using either, you can configure a [*proxy*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) for a specific URL, to be forwarded to the application, i.e.

```
curl http://example.com
> serve /www/example.com/index.php

curl http://example.com/api/abc
> serve http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc
```

In your apache config file, *assuming that once started, your jar file binds to port 8080*.

```
ProxyPass           /api        http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse    /api        http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Comment: if the app is a gui app without http interface, this won't help much...